# Php code not rendering in Views loaded in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller which has following function

```
public function listartistes () {

        $this->set_language();

        $this->data['title'] = "Create Your Own Show Today";
        $this->data['meta_title'] = "Create Your Own Show Today";
        $this->data['meta_desc'] = "Create Your Own Show Today";


            $this->data['content']  = 'artiste/list';

            $this->data['artistes'] = $this->artistes_m->getAllArtistes(); 

        $this->load->vars($this->data);
        $this->load->view('template');
    }
```

As you can see the controller is loading the `template view`  and inside template view we load the 'content' file like this this

```
 <div class="container-full">

        <?=$this->load->view($content);?>
    </div>
```

So far so good . but when I try to put any PHP code in `list` which is inside

`/artiste/list` its not showing on my browser only blank screen

Comment: you question and description is not clear. Which file inside `/artiste/list`? and what you tried there. Moreover use of `$this->load->view()` should not be like that how you are using

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: Show the code for `artiste/list` please.

Comment: And your vars function to question

Answer (score 0):

The partial pattern in CodeIgniter allows consecutive views to be loaded, not embedded ones.  So this means that you might need a partial for header, content and footer for example instead of an outer template and inner [content] template.

So while you may have to adjust what markup and data is in which view, you will probably be best off putting
`$this->load->view($content);` on the line after `$this->load->view('template');` in the controller.  I don't think that CodeIgniter is capable of loading views from within views.